# 'Expiration time buffer' of SessionSecurityTokenHandler of WIF 4.5 in Azure web role

Tags: timeout, token, wif, azure-web-roles, acs

everyone.

What does 'Expiration time buffer' mean? Let me explain this to you.

In my Azure Cloud service project, there is only one Web Role. And I integrated the ACS namespace enabled with some identity provider. And the identity provider will issue an token. Anyhow, there will be a SessionSecurityToken instance. And my web role will handle its expiration.

Here is the sample code,

```
void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("SessionAuthentication_SessionSecurityTokenReceived event");
        SessionSecurityToken sessionToken = e.SessionToken;            
        if (sessionToken.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("SessionSecurityToken with token expiration time {0} expired at {1}. Its key expiration time is {2}",
                sessionToken.ValidTo,
                DateTime.UtcNow,
                sessionToken.KeyExpirationTime);
            Response.Write("{\"message\":\"token timeout\"}");
        }
    }
```

However, not each time when sessionToken.ValidTo less than DateTime.UtcNow will trigger the token expiration exception.

```
Message string  SessionSecurityToken with token expiration time 06/13/2013 09:12:31 expired at 06/13/2013 09:12:37. Its key expiration time is 06/13/2013 09:12:31; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event

Message string  SessionSecurityToken with token expiration time 06/13/2013 09:12:31 expired at 06/13/2013 09:14:37. Its key expiration time is 06/13/2013 09:12:31; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event

Message string  SessionSecurityToken with token expiration time 06/13/2013 09:12:31 expired at 06/13/2013 09:16:37. Its key expiration time is 06/13/2013 09:12:31; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event

Message string  SessionSecurityToken with token expiration time 06/13/2013 09:12:31 expired at 06/13/2013 09:35:32. Its key expiration time is 06/13/2013 09:12:31; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event
```

And only the last time checking will trigger the exception, like this.

```
    Message string  <TraceSource>System.IdentityModel</TraceSource>
<Object>&lt;TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"&gt;&lt;TraceIdentifier&gt;http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx&lt;/TraceIdentifier&gt;&lt;Description&gt;Throwing an exception.&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;AppDomain&gt;/LM/W3SVC/1273337584/ROOT-1-130155861607927929&lt;/AppDomain&gt;&lt;Exception&gt;&lt;ExceptionType&gt;System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089&lt;/ExceptionType&gt;&lt;Message&gt;ID4255: The SecurityToken is rejected because the validation time is out of range.
ValidTo: '6/13/2013 9:12:31 AM'
ValidFrom: '6/13/2013 9:02:32 AM'
Current time: '6/13/2013 9:35:32 AM'&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;StackTrace&gt;   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSession(SessionSecurityToken securityToken)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
   at System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.ValidateSessionToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken)
   at System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalFromSessionToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken)
   at System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken, Boolean writeCookie)
   at System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp;amp;amp; completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
&lt;/StackTrace&gt;&lt;ExceptionString&gt;System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException: ID4255: The SecurityToken is rejected because the validation time is out of range.
ValidTo: '6/13/2013 9:12:31 AM'
ValidFrom: '6/13/2013 9:02:32 AM'
Current time: '6/13/2013 9:35:32 AM'&lt;/ExceptionString&gt;&lt;/Exception&gt;&lt;/TraceRecord&gt;</Object>
```

So can anyone explain this behavior? What's the problem? How to avoid this?

Thanks.

Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default behavior of the SessionAuthenticationModule by setting your own timeout. I actually ran into an issue of needing to implement this to get around a 2 min timeout window of the SAML Token being issued by the Identity Provider (non-Azure) I was connecting to.

You can do this by either subclassing the SessionAuthenticationModule or handling the SessionSecurityTokenReceived event within the Global.asax.

Here's an example borrowed from the ["Programming Windows Identity Foundation" book by Vittorio Bertocci](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JDMPBXW) that make the expiration work on a 2 minute rolling window. Although you'll have to change the namespaces to "System.IdentityModel" since they've changed when Windows Identity Foundation was added to the .NET Framework 4.5.

```
<%@ Application Language=”C#” %>
<%@ Import Namespace=”Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web” %>
<%@ Import Namespace=”Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens” %>
<script runat=”server”>
    void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived
        (object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime validFrom = e.SessionToken.ValidFrom;
        DateTime validTo = e.SessionToken.ValidTo;
        double halfSpan = (validTo – validFrom).TotalMinutes / 2;
        if ( validFrom.AddMinutes( halfSpan ) < now && now < validTo )
        {
            SessionAuthenticationModule sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule;
            e.SessionToken = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
                    e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal,
                    e.SessionToken.Context,
                    now, now.AddMinutes(2), e.SessionToken.IsPersistent);
            e.ReissueCookie = true;
        }
    }     
//...
```